# Read only Blob Metadata

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I read blobs from Azure blob storage

```
CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();
List<Documents> blobs = new List<Documents>();

BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
BlobResultSegment resultSegment = container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("", true, BlobListingDetails.All, 100, continuationToken, null, null).Result;
foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
{…}
```

is it possible to read only the metadata (Url, created, … )from the blob and not the blob itself? So can safe traffic and have a better performance.

Regard
Stefan

Comment: What does the code you show here do? It's certainly not downloading the blob itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. See the code below:

```
            BlobContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
            var resultSegment=cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync("", true, BlobListingDetails.All, 100, continuationToken, null, null).Result;
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in resultSegment.Results)
            {
                #need a type conversion here
                var temp = item as CloudBlockBlob;

                #this line of code is needed for fetch attribute and metadata.
                temp.FetchAttributes();
                Console.WriteLine("URL: {0}", temp.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Creation time: {0}", temp.Properties.Created.ToString());
            }
```

The test result:

[image]

BTW, the `(Url, created, … )` you mentioned are blob properties. If you want to get metadata of blob, you should follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata#setting-and-retrieving-metadata) and make sure you have set metadata before.